# How to exclude package from Scala SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I am at loss. I am using Scala with SBT and I had to add databricks dependency (link dependencies i get when I install databricks-connect) via unmanagedBase in the build.sbt and now when I try to run the application I get this error. I have tried excluding packages but nothing helps. Maybe I am doing it wrong. Could someone please help me. What package should I exclude to make this thing work since I am getting ***org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext?***[image]

Comment: What did you try to exclude SBT dependency? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is happening (and to prevent this in the future), you probably need to read and understand [SLF4J user manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, such as java.util.logging, logback and reload4j.

In [Binding with a logging framework at deployment time](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) section it says:

> ##### *slf4j-log4j12-1.7.35.jar*
>
> Binding/provider for log4j version 1.2, a widely used logging framework.
>
> ##### *logback-classic-1.2.10.jar (requires logback-core-1.2.10.jar)*
>
> There are also SLF4J bindings/providers external to the SLF4J project, e.g. logback which implements SLF4J natively.

First you'd have to decide if you want log4j as the logger implementation or logback. The screenshot doesn't show `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:something`, but is it included?

Assuming you want to exclude log4j binding, then that's the one you need to exclude.

To exclude something from all dependencies in a subproject:

```scala
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
)
```

For more details, see [Exclude Transitive Dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies).

Comment: I really am still at loss... I don't really understand where the cast conflicts happen.